# Applet + Http Get Requests to other Url's

Tags: java, applet, httpclient

I have the following class:

```
public class TestApplet extends JApplet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2137477433249866949L;

    private JTextArea display;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        //Create the text area and make it uneditable.
        display = new JTextArea( 1, 80 );
        display.setEditable( false );

        //Set the layout manager so that the text area
        //will be as wide as possible.
        setLayout( new GridLayout( 1, 0 ) );

        //Add the text area to the applet.
        add( new JScrollPane( display ) );

        String getResult = getResult();

        display.setText( getResult );

    }

    public static void main( final String[] args ) {
        System.out.println( new TestApplet().getResult() );
    }

    private String getResult() {
        String getResult = "";
        try {
            GetMethod getMethod = new GetMethod( "http://www.google.com" );
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

            httpClient.executeMethod( getMethod );

            getResult = getMethod.getResponseBodyAsString();
        }
        catch ( Exception exception ) {
            getResult = ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace( exception );
        }
        return getResult;
    }
```

When I run it local it works fine. However, when I run it on the app server I get:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission www.google.com resolve)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2SecurityManager.checkConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetSocketAddress.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:80)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:122)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
    at com.test.TestApplet.init(TestApplet.java:40)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The jar **is** signed, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Does anyone see any obvious problems with this?

Thanks.

**EDIT #1:**
Here is the html source:

```
<html>
<title>
1.1 TestApplet
</title>
<body>
<h1>
TestApplet
</h1>

    <applet 
        code="com.test.TestApplet" 
        archive="testapplet-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar"
        width=100% 
        height=100%>
    </applet>

</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT #2**

Output from running requested command:

C:\workspaces\workspace-helios-main\testapplet\target>jarsigner -verify testapplet-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
jar verified.

Warning:
This jar contains entries whose signer certificate has expired.

Re-run with the -verbose and -certs options for more details.

Comment: @javamonkey79: "The jar **is** signed, .."  Do you get a prompt to trust the code as the applet is loading?  Is the applet called by JavaScript?

Comment: The applet is called in the html directly - I will edit and post the html source. I don't get a prompt, but I did use the jarsigner utility to sign it.

Comment: @javamonkey79: "I don't get a prompt.."  What output is produced by `jarsigner -verify testapplet-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`?

Comment: Added an edit to answer your question.

Comment: @javamonkey79: AFAIR the JRE *used to* allow the loading of Jars signed by an expired certificate.  Recently Sun/Oracle have been tightening security, it would not surprise me if that possibility had been shut down.  Try signing the applet fresh with an unexpired certificate.

Comment: Also check the settings in the [Java Control Panel](http://pscode.org/player.jnlp) - there may be something amongst them that prevents expired certificates.

Comment: I don't see anything in the Java Control Panel to change this. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the applet's `init()` in [`AccessController#doPrivileged()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/AccessController.html).

```
public void init() {
    AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<Object> {
        @Override 
        public Object run() {
            // Put your original init() here.
            return null;
        }
    });
}
```

#### See also:

- [The Java Tutorials - Making Extensions Secure - Setting Privileges for Extensions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/security/policy.html)
- [Java SE Documentation - API for Privileged Blocks](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/doprivileged.html)

Comment: I tried this. I think I might need to do something with certificates and what not to sign it to make it work. Hmmm...